# How to get a Set from a list of objects using Java Streams

Tags: java, collections, java-8, java-stream

This might be a simple Java streams question. Say, I have a `List<Student>` object.

```
public class Student {
    public String name;
    public Set<String> subjects;

    public Set<String> getSubjects() {
        return subjects;
    }
}
```

How can I get all the subjects taken by the list of students?

I can do this using a for each loop. How can I convert the below code to use Streams?

```
for (Student student : students) {
    subjectsTaken.addAll(student.getSubjects());
}
```

Here is my attempt at using Java 8 streams. This gives me an `Incompatible types` error.

```
Set<String> subjectsTaken = students.stream()
        .map(student -> student.getSubjects())
        .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your current code produces a `Set<Set<String>>`, not a `Set<String>`.

You should use `flatMap`, not `map`:

```
Set<String> subjectsTaken = 
    students.stream() // Stream<Student>
           .flatMap(student -> student.getSubjects().stream()) // Stream<String>
           .collect(Collectors.toSet()); // Set<String>
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
Set<String> subjectsTaken = 
                   students.stream()
                           .map(Student::getSubjects)
                           .flatMap(Set::stream) 
                           .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

The idea is to map the students to their subjects first, then flatten the `Stream<Set<String>>` to `Stream<String>` and finally collect the stream to a `Set`.

---

I would suggest you to use *method references* instead of *lambda expressions* where it's possible (if it doesn't degrade readability).

Answer (score 1):

A different alternative using `Stream<T>#<R>collect` :

```
students.stream()
    .map(Student::getSubjects)
    .<Set<String>>collect(HashSet::new, Collection::addAll, Collection::addAll)
```